# auto numbering with nl2br function

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a data from the database that store user's input from a Textarea box.

This is an example of user's input in the Textarea box;

```
iPhone
Samsung
Nokia
```

When I saved it into the database, I want to display that data to become like this in a table;

```
1. iPhone
2. Samsung
3. Nokia
```

So how am I going to display the data with the numbering?

This is my code so far;

```
<table>

     <td align="left"><?php echo nl2br($sis_sistem) ?></td>

</table>
```

Note : $sis_sistem is the variable that store the data from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`explode()` into an array on the line breaks, then iterate over it.  Rather than numbering them with plain text, you ought to make them a proper HTML ordered list `<ol>`

```
// Get an array of items from lines
$list = explode("\n", $sis_sistem);

// Open an ordered list
echo "<ol>";
// Output the items as list elements
foreach ($list as $num => $item) {
  echo "<li>" . htmlspecialchars($item) . "</li>";
}
echo "</ol>";
```